# How do I keep child object from sliding away from parent as the parent moves?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, parent-child

```
 public GameObject Miffy;
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
 {
     //when space key is pressed and collider is miffy(tagged Player)
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P) && collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
     {
         Ball.transform.parent = Miffy.transform;

         Ball.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
     }
 }
 private void Update()
 {
     //when key D is pressed miffy is no longer parent to ball object.
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
     {
         Ball.transform.SetParent(null);
     }
 }
```

child object (Ball) increasing distance as parent(Miffy) object moves about.

Comment: This is not a question about Visual Studio, so I have removed the tag.

Comment: Well, OnTriggerEnter will only be there for one frame, so you might be missing the point of contact. Try the same code but use OnTriggerStay to test if this is the problem.
Also, you are using KeyCode.P which is not space...

Comment: Have you made sure the code inside your if is actually being executed? Because I highly doubt it is. `OnTriggerEnter` will only be fired for a single frame (the frame contact is made on), so you will likely not be pressing `P` that exact frame. Try changing it out with `OnTriggerStay(Collider collider)` instead

Comment: @Jax297 sorry I changed the key to P, the onTriggerEnter works i can parent the object to the child  when the parent is moving the child moved too but ends up sliding away from the parent but still moves in the same way as parent.

Comment: is the `Ball` a rigidbody? if so: **Don't** nest Rigidbodies! Rather use a [`FixedJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html)

Comment: @derHugo thanks ive used a fixed joint, but how do i only allow for the fixed joint to apply when miffy collides with the ball.

Comment: `  if (col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null && !hasJoint)
        {
            gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
            gameObject.GetComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = col.rigidbody;
            hasJoint = true;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `Ball` is a `Rigidbody`.

You should **not** nest multiple `Rigidbody` or move a parent of a `Rigidbody` at all.

---

Rather use a [`FixedJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html).

Afaik you can simply do something like

```
private Rigidbody miffyRigidbody;
private FixedJoint BallFixedJoint;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    isColliding = true;
    if (collider.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        miffyRigidbody = collider.attachedRigidbody;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        miffyRigidbody = null;
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if(miffyRigidbody && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    {
        if(!BallFixedJoint)
        {
            BallFixedJoint = Ball.GetComponent<FixedJoint>();
            if(!BallFixedJoint) BallFixedJoint = Ball.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
        }

        BallFixedJoint.connectedBody = Miffy.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.P))
    {
        if(!BallFixedJoint)
        {
            BallFixedJoint = Ball.GetComponent<FixedJoint>();
            if(!BallFixedJoint) BallFixedJoint = Ball.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
        }

        BallFixedJoint.connectedBody = null;
    }
}
```